# musb Bubble Interrupt Error in Beaglebone patch path not found

Tags: beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am new in beaglebone black. BBone Device is connected to the GSM Module on the USB port. I faced some issue like;

- 1 USB Port not initialize
- 2 Beaglebone abruptly Off
- 3 Beaglebone Restated

I have to find some patch for controlling bubble interrupt but I am not finding that patch path in the beaglebone device.

Pls see below patch link;

https://marc.info/?l=git-commits-head&m=144331613106445&w=2

Can Anybody faced similar type problem????
And finding a solution then reply me...

Answer (score 0):

Do you supply the power from the jack? Not from the usb right?
Where the GSM module takes the power? Does it take from the Beaglebone **USB_VBUS**?

If the GSM module takes the power from the USB_VBUS of BeagleBone or any IO from the BeagleBone. It is possible to cut the connection and restart because, there is an over current protection on the hardware.

It is an important point that what are the power sources of Beaglebone and GSM module? Also, GSM modules maximum current increase the 2A.

Comment: Hi Dear,  Thank you for reply......   Do you supply the power from the jack? = Yes to BBone @ 5V/2A using Jack.      Where the GSM module takes the power?    =  GSM Module takes power from external not BBone.

Comment: Hi Dear,  I added some thing on my problem is that,                                     
           this problem is happened when i restarted/rebooted BBone Black Device.